# Can't get metabox value (a url) returned using WPAlchemy

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I'm using the WP Alchemy class to add custom metaboxes to templates in the admin panel and pull results from those metaboxes into the theme front-end. Here is the relevant code in content-link.php (in the loop - in Twenty Eleven Theme).

```
<a href="<?php display_url_info(); ?>"><img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/external-link-red03.png"/></a>
```

Right now the link shows just the permalink instead of the url in the metabox. If I hardcode a url in there instead, the custom url shows up on the post. I've verified it being properly stored under _custom_meta in the db (and successfully implemented metabox display in other templates. Here's the value in the db:

```
a:1:{s:5:"links";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:6:"domain";s:25:"http://stackexchange.com/";s:13:"post_link_url";s:48:"http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask";}}}
```

Here's my plugin file:

```
$basic_metabox = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox (

    array (
    'id' => '_custom_meta',
    'title' => 'Basic Meta',
    'template' => ABSPATH . 'wp-content/themes/beernews-child-theme/custom/basic-meta.php',
    'types' => array('post','link')
    )

);

   add_filter('beernews-child-theme_post', 'display_url_info');

function display_url_info() {

    // usually needed
    global $basic_metabox;

    // get the meta data for the current post
    $basic_metabox->the_meta(); ?>

    <?php if ($basic_metabox->get_the_value('post_link_url')) {

    echo $basic_metabox->the_value('post_link_url');

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `display_url_info` function to

```
<?php
add_filter('beernews-child-theme_post', 'display_url_info');

function display_url_info() {
    // usually needed
    global $basic_metabox;
    $basic = $basic_metabox->the_meta(); 

    if($basic['post_link_url']) {
        echo $basic['post_link_url'];
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR : "post_link_url" empty';
    }
}
?>
```

*And not to be a jerk, but I would like to point out that WP Alchemy is not a plugin but rather a PHP Class. I just do not want other people to get confused.*

Comment: here's what I see on hovering over the link...localhost/wordpress/><br/><b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: post_link_url in <b>c:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/wp-content/plugins/meta-box-junk/meta-box-junk.php</b> on line <b>229</b><br/>

Comment: I tried adding this but no luck. No idea what I'm doing really..  $basic_url = isset( $basic['post_link_url'] ) ? esc_attr( $basic['post_link_url'] ) : '';

Comment: Hm. Try to do some debugging. (1) Instead of putting it in a function write it directly in your theme. (2) Can you also post where you defined $basic_metabox;

Comment: Yeah I turned on debug in wp-config. Nothing came up. Not sure what other debugging I can do. I edited my post to add where I defined $basic_metabox. As for implementing some other way, it's the exact same fashion that I'm implementing other boxes...hmmm.

Comment: I want to try one more thing. Change the return to echo. I updated my script in my answer.

Comment: now i just see localhost/wordpress/ERROR:

Comment: Okay so that means `$basic['post_link_url']` is not being set.

Comment: Well, remember that I tested it with just a plain ole url there in the template and it output the url just fine as part of the conditional. Which I think would mean that $basic['post_link_url'] IS set? It is only when I try to pull from postmeta table in that conditional that I have the issue.

Comment: Here is the working code: http://pastebin.com/ziak10QP

Not sure how to explain why it works though. It was handed to me by a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using the filter exactly ...

I would do the following in the theme file:

```
<?php global $basic_metabox; /* this is just needed once */ ?>
<?php if ($basic_metabox->have_value('post_link_url')) { ?>
<a href="<?php $basic_metabox->the_value('post_link_url'); ?>"><img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/external-link-red03.png"/></a> 
<?php } ?>
```

Also note that `get_the_value()` and `the_value()` are different, the first returning a value and the second echoing out a value.